# SQL find partial duplicates in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with partial duplicate values in one of the column and that is the primary key on the table. I tried to write a query to find those duplicates and couldn't figure it out.
Ex:

```
Taxi(Number, id) - Number is primary key on the table
Values(123, 253)
Values(123-, 253)
Values(1 23,253)
```

These all are treated as duplicates according to the requirements.
This is the query I tried with no luck

```
select * from taxi t where exists(
select 1 from taxi t2
where t1.id = t2.id
and t2.number like t1.number||'%')
```

This is giving me all the values back. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does the data ALL look like? If it is just those three values you can easily write an expression that handles that. However, if you have 100 different perturbations of those... We need to know what the pattern is that has created these duplicates of an intended primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `translate()` will do what you want:

```
select translate(number, '0- ', '0') as fixed_number
```

All the characters after `0` in the first string will be removed.

So, if you want the duplicates:

```
select t.*
from (select translate(number, '0- , '0') as fixed_number, t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by translate(number, '0- ', '0')) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
order by fixed_number;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did a small tweak to  translate to add missing '0'. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you have messed up data.  Try selecting and grouping using a regular expression which removes the blank and '-' [and other characters].  any set having count(*) > 1 is a duplicate.